# youtube chrome extension that block youtube movie by channel name

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wanna create youtube chrome extension that block youtube movie by channel name.
Specifically, it is as follows.

when youtube movie is loaded, the program checks already registered list and if a channel name is registered in the list, redirecting a certain page.

However, when I want to create redirect function, I don't know which method to use from the ones listed in the official document of chrome extension.

please let me know I should use which method.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no such method. You'll have to implement the check inside a content script, probably. Then you can redirect the page via location.assign